# SQL query is not returning duplicate values, it's only showing unique values

Tags: javascript, sql, typescript, postgresql

I am making a call to return the values from a table given their ids.
My table looks like:

```
ID      VALUE
'123'  'Apple'
'123'  'Apple'
'123'  'Apple'
'789'  'Orange'
```

I have all of the ids in an array (['123', '123', '123', '789]) which is then passed as a value parameter in the query.

```
const result = await db.manyOrNone(
   `SELECT value from 'Table' WHERE id IN (${idArray.map(id => `'${id}'`)})`
)
```

However, when I log the result, it only shows me the unique values. It also reverses the order. How would I fix it to return all the values in the same order?

Below is what the result looks like:

```
[
   { value: 'Orange'},
   { value: 'Apple'}
]
```

This is what I want:

```
[
   { value: 'Apple'},
   { value: 'Apple'},
   { value: 'Apple'},
   { value: 'Orange'},
]
```

Comment: What is the structure of your table? Can you go to `psql` and run `\d+ tablename`?

Comment: `from 'Table'` is invalid SQL to begin with. Does this really work? But with the data as shown, Postgres **will** return all rows: https://dbfiddle.uk/28lTcfv5 (although the repetition of the value `123` won't change anything)

Comment: @UrošAnđelić column (where id and name are), type, nullable, default